# Sas-Macro Variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS code applied to a single alphanumeric column to remove the character ':' in the column, I would like to apply this code to all the alphanumeric columns of table1 automatically with macro variable

```
data p;
set  table1;
prenom1 = COMPRESS(VVALUE(prenom),':');
drop prenom;
rename prenom1=prenom;
run;
```

but the code doesn't work:

```
select name into :alpha_cols separated by ' ' 
from dictionary.columns
 where libname = 'work' and memname = 'table1' and type = 'char'; 
quit; 

data work.P; 
set table1; 
%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&alpha_cols)); 
%let col_name = %scan(&alpha_cols, &i); 
&col_name._new = %sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(vvalue(&col_name)), ':')) ; %sysfunc(rename) &col_name._new = &col_name.; 
%end; 
run;
```

Comment: Why do you think a macro variable would help? What would the macro variable do for you? What would the macro variable contain?  The code you show is NOT removing colons from any variable's values.  It is making a NEW variable that contains the displayed value of the a variable which has had the colons removed.

Comment: that's what i want, but the code doesn't work: '
proc sql noprint;
   select name into :alpha_cols separated by ' '
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname = 'work' and memname = 'table1' and type = 'char';
quit;
data work.P;
    set table1;
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&alpha_cols));
      %let col_name = %scan(&alpha_cols, &i);
   &col_name._new = %sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(vvalue(&col_name)), ':')) ;
      %sysfunc(rename) &col_name._new = &col_name.;
   %end;
run;
'

Answer (score 0):

To make the list of variable names you need to query the metadata using only uppercase LIBNAME and MEMNAME values, since that is how the metadata appears in that view.  Also I find it helps to always use NLITERAL() function when generating lists of variables just in case someone has accidentally set the VALIDVARNAME option to ANY.

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name)
     , nliteral(cats(name,'new'))
  into :alpha_cols separated by '|' 
     , :new_cols separated by '|'
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = 'TABLE1'
    and type = 'char'
;
%let nvars=&sqlobs; 
quit;
```

Now it is easy to use a %DO loop to generate one assignment statement per variable in the list.  If you want to re-use the name then you need to drop the old variable, you cannot have two variables with the same name.  You don't need to add %SYSFUNC() calls around the SAS code you are using the macro logic to generate.  That is only needed when you want the SAS functions to actually execute while the macro processor is working.

```
data P; 
  set table1; 
%do i = 1 %to &nvars;
  %let col_name = %scan(&alpha_cols,&i,|);
  %let new_name = %scan(&new_cols,&i,|); 
  &new_name = compress(vvalue(&col_name), ':'); 
  rename &new_name = &col_name ;
  drop &col_name ;
%end; 
run;
```

You cannot use a %DO Loop in "open code", only inside a macro.  To use the %DO loop you must enclose this in a macro definition and then execute the macro.

So perhaps something like:

```
%macro convert(indata,outdata);
%local alpha_cols new_cols nvars i col_name new_name;

proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name)
     , nliteral(cats(name,'new'))
  into :alpha_cols separated by '|' 
     , :new_cols separated by '|'
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = %upcase("&indata")
    and type = 'char'
;
%let nvars=&sqlobs; 
quit;

data &outdata; 
  set &indata; 
%do i = 1 %to &nvars;
  %let col_name = %scan(&alpha_cols,&i,|);
  %let new_name = %scan(&new_cols,&i,|); 
  &new_name = compress(vvalue(&col_name)) ':'); 
  rename &new_name = &col_name ;
  drop &col_name ;
%end; 
run;
%mend convert;
```

Example call:

```
data table1;
  name='fred';
  reason='A:b';
run;
options mprint;
%convert(indata=table1,outdata=P);
```

Resulting SAS log:

```
817  %convert(indata=table1,outdata=want);
MPRINT(CONVERT):   proc sql noprint;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   select nliteral(name) , nliteral(cats(name,'new')) into :alpha_cols separated by '|' , :new_cols separated by
'|' from dictionary.columns where libname = 'WORK' and memname = "TABLE1" and type = 'char' ;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


MPRINT(CONVERT):   data want;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   set table1;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   namenew = compress(vvalue(name), ':');
MPRINT(CONVERT):   rename namenew = name ;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   drop name ;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   reasonnew = compress(vvalue(reason), ':');
MPRINT(CONVERT):   rename reasonnew = reason ;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   drop reason ;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   run;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.TABLE1.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 1 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: thank you but the execution of this code gives me an error :j

Comment: 44         %do i = 1 %to &nvars;
ERROR: The %DO statement is not valid in open code.
45           %let col_name = %scan(&alpha_cols,&i,|);
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.

Comment: ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       &i 
ERROR: Argument 2 to macro function %SCAN is not a number.
46           %let new_name = %scan(&new_cols,&i,|);
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       &i 
ERROR: Argument 2 to macro function %SCAN is not a number.

Comment: i hope that you can help me M

Comment: Either I is not a macro variable (or it is a macro variable that does not contain digits). Or the value of NEW_COLS has commas in it that are not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Either I is not a macro variable.? 
I didn't understand; can you help me please

Comment: my NEW_COLS contains '_'

Comment: You cannot use the %DO loop in open code.  The error you mentioned about %SCAN() is caused by calling it without a number as the second argument.  That could either happen because the second argument you tried to pass was wrong. Or because you used a macro variable's value as the first argument and the value of the macro variable had commas in it so something in the what you thought was the first argument became the second argument because the macro processor used the commas when evaluating the %SCAN() function call.

Comment: I believe that the macro will be fine this time but there is still a small problem in your code ; ERROR 22-322: Erreur de syntaxe, l'une des valeurs suivantes est attendue : !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, ;, <, <=, <>, =, >, ><, >=, 
              AND, EQ, GE, GT, IN, LE, LT, MAX, MIN, NE, NG, NL, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Comment: MPRINT(CONVERT):   ORI_SCPnew = compress(vvalue(ORI_SCP)), ':');
MPRINT(CONVERT):   rename ORI_SCPnew = ORI_SCP ;
MPRINT(CONVERT):   drop ORI_SCP ;
NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "CONVERT".
55             &new_name = compress(vvalue(&col_name)), ':');
                                                      _
                                                      22
                                                      200

Comment: There is an extra ) that is ending the COMPRESS() too soon.

Comment: sorry M for this last message lol, isn't there a possibility to keep the same position of the columns as in the original table?

Comment: Search for questions for setting variable order in SAS.  One way would be to add another SQL query to generate a macro variable with all of the variable names in order.  You would need to have the NEW variable names replace the old names (use CASE to do this).  You would need to use space as the delimiter.  You would need to order the query by VARNUM.  Then you could use that macro variable to help you generate a retain statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use macros at all?

Use array over character variables:

```
data have;
 set sashelp.class(obs=3);
 name_age = catx(":", name, age);
 name_sex = catx(":", name, sex);
run;
proc print data=have;
run;

data got;
  set  have;
  array C _character_;
  do over C;
    C = COMPRESS(C,':');
  end;
run;

proc print data=got;
run;
```